# Postgres Query Logging for Windows

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql, logging

I have an application which is based on a Postgres database and I need to be able to examine the requests the application sends of the database.

I want to have Postgres log all of the queries it receives somewhere that I can examine them in order to rebuild some of its functionality in another application.

Can someone recommend a simple way to logging the queries Postgres receives in a Windows operating system?

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit your postgresql.conf for PostgreSQL server, and either change log_statement to 'all' or change log_min_duration_statement to 0.

After the change you have to reload PostgreSQL configuration, and the queries will be logged to PostgreSQL log.

Comment: For those of us that are new to Postgres could you expand on how to "reload PostgreSQL configuration" and where to find the log please.

Comment: You can realod your pg configuration by executing select pg_reload_conf(); in pgadmin.
You can find your pg logs in : C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\{version}\data\log